# How do I create a table when a module is installed?

Tags: 8, database, installation

I want to add a custom table when a module I develop is installed. The code I am using doesn't seem to work, as the *post* table isn't created.

What is wrong with the code I am using?

```php
/**
 * Installs the database schema.
 */
function mymodule_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('post');
}

/**
 * Uninstalls the database schema.
 */
function mymodule_uninstall() {
  drupal_uninstall_schema('post');
}

/**
* Creates the tables using the schema API.
*/
function mymodule_schema() {
  $schema['post'] = array(
    'description' => 'description pour la table post',
    'fields' => array(
      'pid' => array(
        'description' => 'post id',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'title' => array(
        'description' => 'title',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'body' => array(
        'description' => 'body',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'created' => array(
              'description' => 'created',
              'not null' => TRUE,
              'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
            ),
      'primary key' => array('pid'),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It probably won't be an issue, but I would prefix my custom tables with my custom module's name.

Comment: for example brother ?

Comment: For example, use `$schema['mymodule_post']` so your table is *mymodule_post*.

Comment: thank you it works , but from where this error cam from ==>  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version f  
  or the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'title',                                                                                                  
  `body` VARCHAR DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'body',                                                                                                                     
  `cre' at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems with your [`hook_schema`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Database%21database.api.php/function/hook_schema) implementation.

1. You are missing a `return` statement at the end of your function to return the schema.
2. `primary_key` needs to be outside the fields array on the same level as the `fields` and the `description`.

---

```
/**
 * Implements hook_schema().
 */
function MYMODULE_schema() {
  $schema['post'] = [
    'description' => 'description pour la table post',
    'fields' => [
      'pid' => [
        'description' => 'post id',
        'type' => 'int',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
      'title' => [
        'description' => 'title',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
      'body' => [
        'description' => 'body',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ],
      'created' => [
        'description' => 'created',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'mysql_type' => 'timestamp',
      ],
    ],
    // primary_key needs to be outside the fields array.
    'primary key' => ['pid'],
  ];
  // Don't forget to return the schema.
  return $schema;
}
```

Comment: I would also add that `hook_install()` and `hook_uninstall()` aren't necessary to create and delete tables.